# "Failed to load resource" when using Realtime API

Tags: google-drive-realtime-api

When working with the realtime API I sometimes get this error:

Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 400 (Unknown SID) https://drive.google.com/otservice/bind?id=13bt-KPBrU6WRdWSqLBl2cni366tuZqT…&RID=rpc&SID=7808B6FE50C4A180&CI=0&AID=15&TYPE=xmlhttp&zx=64nyubda57et&t=1

What does it mean?

Answer (score 1):

This error is a known issue with the Realtime API and we are working to track down the cause. In general, the API will automatically retry the request and you can ignore the error.